# Sharing variables between different macros

Tags: crystal-lang

How to access vars in macro that are set in another macro
e.g.

```
macro foo(arg)
 {% SHARED_VAR = arg%}
 p {{arg}}
end

macro baz

 p {{ SHARED_VAR }}

end

foo("foo")
baz #=> prints "foo"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is just not a feature of the language, and probably for good reasons.

Some alternatives:
Use a constant instead, but you cannot do compile-time things with it:

```
macro foo(arg)
  SHARED_VAR = {{arg}}
end

macro baz
  p SHARED_VAR
end

foo("foo")
baz #=> prints "foo"
```

Or simply call the other macro with the additional information:

```
macro foo(arg)
  {% shared_var = arg %}
  baz({{shared_var}})
  p {{arg}}
end

macro baz(arg)
  p {{arg}}
end

foo("foo") #=> prints "foo"
```